# New code Insert won't let me insert code

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Using Chrome v37.0.2062.124 m, when trying to use the new Code snippet feature to insert code, I can type the code, run the code, tidy the code, but it would not let me insert the code.

I tried with both the checkbox checked, and unchecked.

The code I was trying to insert was very simple :

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="background: url(https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png);"></div>
```

I attempted this both with and without the inline html style.  No javascripts were required and the inline style was due to what the poster of the question was asking for  (to crop images), so this showed them how to do it with minimal change to their HTML.

The problem:  Code snippet won't insert this code.

Is this a problem with support for Google Chrome ?  or is there something special I need to do in order to be able to use this to insert code ?   I think it's fantastic that SO has added this feature, however if it partially works, then that could be a problem.   I have seen blocks inserted using this method which is how I first became aware of it's existance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a dupe, but not sure where.  I can repro.

Comment: if it was a dupe, im certain it would have come up when I searched for it, however if what you say is true, then you must already know the answer. -  it seems it's not coming up when you search for it either, so this remains a question that should be answered so it is visible in search results.

Comment: The dupe might be on [meta.se]

Comment: @Will Yeah, [the issue has been raised on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240486/snippets-editor-wont-insert-and-close-on-so?noredirect=1#comment788101_240486), but it was also raised here. So, yeah, a dup. :)

Comment: Canonical VTC cast.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Btw, search can sometimes be really suckish. The original does have answers, and the MSE post has an answer, but it doesn't look like a dev has taken a look yet, and that's who's going to be able to give a definitive answer, likely in the form of "Hey, thanks for finding this, we fixed it and it will be updated in the next deployment."

Comment: Reading the link now.  Thank you for locating ...  I am just curious as to why it works for some people and not othere -.-.  Even went as far as to disable all my extensions (not many, basically adblock and roboform and colorpicker).

Comment: Something probably just broke in the last deployment. It's really hard to say.

Comment: I broke this just before vacation last week, and fixed it this morning. Sorry for the inconvenience. That'll learn me to make changes before vacations...

Comment: Thank you for updating Haney :)